# Angularjs binding to JSON sets value to undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a really tricky issue with nested bindings in some custom directives. I have a JSON structure that looks a bit like this;

```
{
 survey:
    questions:[
        {
        text:'Question 1',
        answers:[
            {
            text:'Answer 1'
            },
            ..        
        ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Each survey has many questions and each question has many answers. I have created directives for the forms for survey and questions. Question directives have nested answer directives. The directives are looped out and bound to the JSON. The HTML looks like this:

The page;

```
<div>
    <survey-form></survey-form>
    <div ng-repeat="question in survey.questions">
         <question-form></question-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The question-form directive;

```
<div>
     <h1>{{question.title}}</h1>
     <div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
          <answer-form></answer-form>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This all appears fine and I get no errors in the console. However seemingly random text attributes are being set to undefined in the underlying JSON as soon as the binding to the form inputs complete. If I bind to none editable elements everything is as expected. Additionally this does not apply to every element in the nested JSON - I see some text values set to undefined and others remain as in the source JSON.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue? Its really annoying and I think maybe a bug in Angular..

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the directives defined? Are you just implicitly relying in the surrounding scope to pass those values, or are you actually setting a local scope in the directive?

Comment: Thanks for the response - yeah implicitly - for example by repeating question I am accessing $scope.question within the directive. I am deliberately avoiding isolating the directive scope as I want the binding to the parent JSON to pass back up

Comment: You can still have it pass back up with two-way binding. I'm not sure whether this is your issue or not, but just as good programming practice I'd very much favour explicitly passing the values as `<question-form question="question">` than to rely on implicitly present scope values.

Comment: Yeah sure I just thought I could rely on the scope inherited from the rg-repeat loop. I will give this a try. Whats weird is that within an individual question/answer I am getting some fields binding fine. I will try to recreate issue in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as question.text instead of question.title? I notice in your JSON it's text. If it's not that, can you provide your directive information for answers, and possibly set up a jsfiddle/plunkr to show it happenning.

Comment: Nah its not and yes I will try to get a jsfiddle recreating the issue